# php array to javascript objects

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

hi there im having a problem adding values to my graph from php array to javascript object so far i have a php values in the array

```
$data=array(5,10,15,20);
```

and i converted it to json to prepare for javascript

```
$js_array = json_encode($data);
```

and heres the javascipt part

data : `<?php echo json_encode( $data );  ?>`

i think it is reading it as

```
data : [5] or data : [5101520]
```

it was suppose to read it as

```
data : [5,10,15,20]
```

thanks guys hoping you can help me

here is the php array storing

```
<?php  
$data = array();

$que = "SELECT name FROM table1 ORDER BY date ASC";

$res = mysql_query($que, $con);

if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

$data[] = $row['name'];

}}

$js_array = json_encode($data);

?>'
```

here is the var dump data echo
    array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ngEh.jpg)=> string(2) "10" [2]=> string(2) "20" [3]=> string(2) "15" }

[image: here is the current output]

Comment: I dont think `$data()=[5,10,15,20];` is valid php ???

Comment: `$data()=[5,10,15,20];` isn't valid PHP. It's close. Please show your *actual output*, not merely what you *think* it is.

Comment: the data in php array is good i checked it using echo in php
sorry if i inputed the wrong syntax but i just want to show the values in php array

Comment: @JoseSamaniego No, it is **not** valid PHP: https://eval.in/54883

Comment: are you just saying $data array is = to this in javascript because that certainly isn't valid

Comment: Im not sure anymore i heard something about a change to the way you can declare Arrays. But i can't remember what it was.

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard Check out the link ComFreek provided, it shows it is invalid.

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard There's a new bracket syntax: `[1,2,3]` vs. `array(1,2,3)`. That's all.

Comment: @JoseSamaniego please show us what `var_dump($data)` prints out

Answer (score 3):

php

```
// array
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5);
// array -> json
$json = json_encode($data);
// print json
echo $json;
```

js with jquery:

```
$.getJSON( "script.php", function( data ) {
console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: By the way, `[1,2,3,4,5]` is perfectly valid syntax. Only the parentheses were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined php array will throw syntax error.

Use like this :

```
<?php
$data=array(5,10,15,20);
print_r(json_encode($data));
?>
```

It'll give you output :

```
data : [5,10,15,20]
```

Here is the demo : http://codepad.org/UVFT6m67

Now you can use this json object with your javascript.